# Проблема с кодировкой в Python: SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-faq

```
self.api.messages.send(peer_id=i, random_id=0,
    message='({group}) {rang} - {user} , добавил ГДЗ к предмету - "{subject}"! Чтобы посмотреть ГДЗ к предмету используйте:\nshow-hw [Название группы](В одно слово!⚠) [Предмет][В одно слово!⚠]'
        .format(group=message.split()[1], rang='Модератор' if (jsonData.check_oneditor(group=message.split()[1],userid=userid) == True)
            else 'Администратор',subject=message.split()[2],user='vk.com/id{id}'.format(id=userid)))
```

Есть такая строка кода, когда запускаю выдаёт ошибку:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd0' in file C:/Users/Moto-Moto/Desktop/BotRemake/mainBot.py on line 131, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Что делать?

Comment: Перестать использовать устаревший десять лет назад Python 2.

Comment: это 3 питон... в то и проблема.

Comment: Тогда остаётся только зарепортить баг разработчикам Python, так как Python 3 не может выдавать такой ошибки.

Comment: Отформатируйте, пожалуйста, строки так, чтобы по ширине влезали...

Comment: http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ , кстати, читали? Применяли?

Comment: Ошибка может означать, что у вас исходник сохранен не в utf-8, а в cp1251, например. Если у вас не utf-8, то кодировка должна быть прописана в начале файла. Но проще пересохранить в utf-8

Comment: @insolor вроде как там вообще системная кодировка берётся. Потому желательно всегда прописывать в исходнике кодировку, даже utf-8.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, нет, Python3 по-умолчанию считает, что исходник в utf-8, дополнительно не нужно ничего прописывать. Цитата [отсюда](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code):  "Python supports writing source code in UTF-8 by default, but you can use almost any encoding if you declare the encoding being used.", "If you don’t include such a comment, the default encoding used will be UTF-8 as already mentioned."

Comment: @insolor не знаю, как у меня так выходило - сохранял файл в utf-8 всегда, и выходила похожая ошибка. Потом добавлял # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- и всё нормально работало. С тех пор на всякий случай во все исходники это прописываю.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич у меня никогда не было проблем, когда сохранял в utf-8. Причем раньше на Windows (XP, 7, 10) сидел, никаких проблем не было, так что системная кодировка не влияет. Ругалось только если по ошибке в cp1251 сохранял. Вот Python2 будет ругаться если coding не указать.

Comment: OMG как-то даже в голову не пришло, что кто-то может сохранить исходник не в UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Данная ошибка:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd0' in file
> C:/Users/Moto-Moto/Desktop/BotRemake/mainBot.py on line 131, but no
> encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for
> details

гласит, что в коде встретился байт, который не удается декодировать кодировкой utf-8, а фактическая кодировка в начале файла не прописана. Это означает, что у вас файл программы сохранен не в кодировке utf-8, а в какой-то другой (если работаете под Windows, то скорее всего в cp1251).

Варианты решения:

1. Просто пересохранить файл в кодировке utf-8. Как конкретно это сделать - находим в поисковике запросом "pycharm как изменить кодировку файла" (вставьте название своего редактора или IDE вместо pycharm) **(рекомендую этот вариант)**
2. Или добавить в начале файла строку с указанием кодировки, как описано в [pep-263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)
   (строка вида `# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-`)

По-умолчанию Python 3 считает, что файл сохранен в кодировке utf-8, поэтому если сохранять в utf-8, то дополнительно указывать кодировку в начале файла не нужно:

> Python supports writing source code in UTF-8 by default, but you can
> use almost any encoding if you declare the encoding being used.
>
> ...
>
> If you don’t include such a comment, the default encoding used will be
> UTF-8 as already mentioned.

Источник: [Unicode HOWTO, раздел "Unicode Literals in Python Source Code"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

В меню Файл выберите Сохранить файл как и затем нажмите кнопку раскрывающегося списка рядом с кнопкой Сохранить. Откроется диалоговое окно Дополнительные параметры сохранения
там меняйте на:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]